# Variables are not passing the correct or any data into query

Tags: mysql, sql

The date variables are not passing correctly in the store procedure. 
This portion returns a null

```
(CONVERT_TZ( (FROM_UNIXTIME(@fromDate/1000)),''UTC'', @timeZone) )AS startingDate, 
(CONVERT_TZ( (FROM_UNIXTIME(@toDate/1000)),''UTC'', @timeZone) ) AS endingDate,
```

These dates are show null

```
l1.started BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate
```

What I am I missing that the values are not passing into the query

```
CREATE PROCEDURE reportFreeCoolingTrackerTest (
        IN fromDate varchar (50),
        IN toDate varchar (50),
        IN timeZone varchar (50))

    BEGIN
            DECLARE startDate varchar (50);
            DECLARE endDate varchar (50);
            DECLARE mylogID Int;

             SET startDate = FROM_UNIXTIME(fromDate/1000);
             SET endDate = FROM_UNIXTIME(toDate/1000);
             SET mylogID = (SELECT logID FROM logs l WHERE l.details LIKE 'FCT%');
             SET @tbl = CONCAT('log',mylogID);

 set @q1 = CONCAT('SELECT 
    i.details,l1.item31985,l1.item31987,
    ((l1.item31985 - l1.item31987)*(time_to_sec(timediff(t2.completed, l1.completed)))) / 3600  AS kwDifference,
    ((l1.item31985 - l1.item31987) *  (substr(l.details, instr(l.details , '':'' ) +1))) AS cost,
    (((l1.item31985 - l1.item31987) *  (substr(l.details, instr(l.details , '':'' ) +1)))
    *(time_to_sec(timediff(t2.completed, l1.completed)) / 3600)) AS costT,
      time_to_sec(timediff(t2.completed, l1.completed)) / 3600 AS coolingHours,
      time_to_sec(timediff(@endDate, @startDate)) / 3600 AS totalTimeRange,
    (CONVERT_TZ( (FROM_UNIXTIME(@fromDate/1000)),''UTC'', @timeZone) )AS startingDate, 
    (CONVERT_TZ( (FROM_UNIXTIME(@toDate/1000)),''UTC'', @timeZone) ) AS endingDate,DATABASE() AS databaseName,
     CASE
        when l1.activityId = t2.activityId THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS errorCheck, t2.completed AS errorDay,a.scheduleType,@lgName,@mylogID  


  FROM logs l 
      INNER JOIN groups g ON g.groupId = l.groupId
      LEFT JOIN groups g1 ON g.parentId = g1.groupId
      LEFT JOIN groups g2 ON g1.parentId = g2.groupId
      LEFT JOIN groups g3 ON g2.parentId = g3.groupId                
      INNER JOIN activities a ON l.logId = a.logId 
      INNER JOIN  ',  @tbl,'  l1 ON a.activityId = l1.activityId ');

   set @q2 = CONCAT(@q1, 'INNER JOIN ', @tbl);

   SET @q3 = CONCAT(@q2, ' t2 ON t2.recordId = l1.recordid + 1
      INNER JOIN items i ON l.logId = i.logId AND i.name LIKE ''%KW%''
      INNER JOIN users u ON l1.userId = u.userId AND i.name LIKE ''%KW%''
     WHERE i.itemID = "31985"  AND  l1.activityId = 1257
      AND l1.started
        BETWEEN @startDate
            AND @endDate
     ORDER BY l1.recordId,l1.started');   

    PREPARE stmt FROM @q3;

     EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
    END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are numerous issues with your code. Here are major ones:

1. You're mixing procedure input parameters and local variables with user(session) variables. E.g. you have an input parameter `fromDate` but you refer to it in a query `@fromDate` which is user(session) variable and has nothing to do with the parameter. That's why you're getting `NULL` instead of actual values.
2. Instead of concatenating query string with variable values you just left variable names as part of string literal.
3. Date string literals (e.g. variables `fromDate` and `startDate`) should be quoted when you interpolate them in query string. Same goes to `timeZone` values.
4. In your query string you're referring to a `@lgName` variable, which most likely doesn't hold any value. And even if it does then instead of passing it through user(session) variable you should've done that through another procedure parameter.
5. This part

   ```
   SET mylogID = (SELECT logID FROM logs l WHERE l.details LIKE 'FCT%');
   ```

   should return the only value, otherwise it will break your code. Using `LIKE` can easily produce multiple rows. That being said either apply `LIMIT 1` (or an aggregate function e.g. `MIN()` or `MAX`) or rewrite it using condition that based on a column(s) which has(have) a PK or  `UNIQE` constraint.
6. `fromDate`,  `startDate`, `mylogID` are local variables. But for some reason you use user variable `@tbl` to hold a table name value. Ditch it and just concatenate `'log'` and `mylogID` value while you building your query string.

That being said your procedure might look something like

```
DELIMITER$$
CREATE PROCEDURE reportFreeCoolingTrackerTest (
  IN fromDate VARCHAR (50),
  IN toDate   VARCHAR (50),
  IN timeZone VARCHAR (50)
)
BEGIN
  DECLARE startDate VARCHAR (50);
  DECLARE endDate   VARCHAR (50);
  DECLARE mylogID   INT;

  SET startDate = FROM_UNIXTIME(fromDate/1000);
  SET endDate   = FROM_UNIXTIME(toDate/1000);
  SET mylogID   = 1; -- (SELECT logID FROM logs WHERE details LIKE 'FCT%' LIMIT 1);

  SET @sql = NULL;
  SET @sql = CONCAT(
  'SELECT i.details,l1.item31985,l1.item31987,
    ((l1.item31985 - l1.item31987) * (time_to_sec(timediff(t2.completed, l1.completed)))) / 3600  AS kwDifference,
    ((l1.item31985 - l1.item31987) * (substr(l.details, instr(l.details , '':'' ) +1))) AS cost,
    (((l1.item31985 - l1.item31987) * (substr(l.details, instr(l.details , '':'' ) +1)))
    *(time_to_sec(timediff(t2.completed, l1.completed)) / 3600)) AS costT,
      time_to_sec(timediff(t2.completed, l1.completed)) / 3600 AS coolingHours,
      time_to_sec(timediff(''', endDate, ''', ''', startDate, ''')) / 3600 AS totalTimeRange,
    CONVERT_TZ(''', startDate, ''', ''UTC'', ''', timeZone, ''') AS startingDate, 
    CONVERT_TZ(''', endDate, ''', ''UTC'', ''', timeZone, ''') AS endingDate,
    DATABASE() AS databaseName,
    CASE WHEN l1.activityId = t2.activityId THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS errorCheck, 
    t2.completed AS errorDay,
    a.scheduleType,
    @lgName,
    ', mylogID, '
  FROM logs l 
       INNER JOIN groups g ON g.groupId = l.groupId
       LEFT JOIN groups g1 ON g.parentId = g1.groupId
       LEFT JOIN groups g2 ON g1.parentId = g2.groupId
       LEFT JOIN groups g3 ON g2.parentId = g3.groupId                
       INNER JOIN activities a ON l.logId = a.logId 
       INNER JOIN log', mylogID, ' l1 ON a.activityId = l1.activityId
       INNER JOIN log', mylogID, ' t2 ON t2.recordId = l1.recordid + 1
       INNER JOIN items i ON l.logId = i.logId AND i.name LIKE ''%KW%''
       INNER JOIN users u ON l1.userId = u.userId AND i.name LIKE ''%KW%''
  WHERE i.itemID = 31985  AND  l1.activityId = 1257
    AND l1.started BETWEEN ''', startDate, ''' AND ''', endDate, '''
  ORDER BY l1.recordId,l1.started');   

  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8cfc3/2)** demo that shows the final query string instead of executing it

Comment: So I obviously have some issues! I generally work in ms sql. The crux of what I need to do is be able to use myLogId as the table name for the join. AND have my variable working.

Comment: OH YES! I had to change several things to get it to work but once i saw your code I was immediately able to see what I was not understanding...it is much like mssql in how it handles variables in stored procedures. Thank you so much for taking the time to do this.